# Saving and Loading a Number Value in a Cookie

Tags: html, variables, cookies

I am working on a small project and I was wondering, how would I go about saving a number variable in a cookie. I have never worked with cookies or session variables before so this is all new to me. So whenever a user opens their browser next (after they logged off saving a variable to a cookie) and navigates to my website the next day or hour, the variable they had before will be that same.

Comment: you can't do it with pure HTML, you have at least to use JavaScript

Comment: I was planning to do that, I just forgot to put that in the post.

Comment: If you are planning to use JavaScript to store your cookies, your should read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

Comment: Yeah, I looked over that earlier, I was wondering how to store variables instead of text like the tutorial.

Comment: The `value` of a cookie **must** be a string. There is no way to store it explicitly as a string, but you can cast the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `localStorage` is what you are looking for.

```
localStorage.setItem("var", 13) 
localStorage.getItem("var") //returns null if not set
```

More info at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

**EDIT:** Those only work with string, and will only return a string, use something like `parseInt()` to store numbers.